# Kafka producer ERROR using "security.protocol"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api

I have a Kerberized cluster with 2 Kafka brokers and 3 Zookeeper nodes.
I have a Java application, in local, ( using kafka-client 2.4.0 ) that must produce and read messages from topics in Kafka brokers.
In input at the VM I gave:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/Users/mypath/kafka_client_jaas.conf
```

I also have a schema registry ( confluent ), in local, connected to the cluster.
To create a Producer a set those options:

```
    Properties producerProps = new Properties();
    producerProps.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    producerProps.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka");
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Constants.KAFKA_BROKERS);
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, user);
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    producerProps.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
```

**error:**

```
java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    row 5: expected [option key], found [null]
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
```

**The problem is caused by**

```
producerProps.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
```

Without this line, the application compiles but I receive:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic TEST not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

What should I do?

P.S. the "`kafka_client_jaas.conf`" should be right, since I use it also with schema registry and it works fine.

**kafka_client_jaas.conf:**

```
KafkaClient { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
useKeyTab=true 
storeKey=true 
keyTab="/Users/path/kafka.service.keytab" \ 
principal="kafka/kafka-broker01.domain.xx@DOMAIN.XX"; };
```

Comment: To really understand how Java processes your Kerberos/JAAS config, you should set `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter added, nothing changed.
I put it both in "VM option" in Intellij Run Configuration and in idea.vmoptions.

Comment: Nothing is meant to change except getting more logs to debug the problem

Comment: If I had to guess based on _"...expected [option key], found [null]..."_, the `Krb5LoginModule` def is not properly terminated with `;` in `jaas.conf`.

Comment: @cricket_007 "nothing changed", because the new log informations doesn't describe much, actually nothing of relevant:
`configfile: reading file:/Users/path/kafka_client_jaas.conf
configparser:  Reading next config entry: KafkaClient`

Comment: What does that backslash (`\\` between keytab and principal) do in conf file? Can you take it out?

Comment: Different parsers I guess. Glad its resolved :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below with the solution